# Node and Express simple POST - 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Surely I'm doing something stupid, because this should be the easiest thing in the world.

All I'm trying to do is perform a POST in an Express route.

My app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

My index.js route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Express'});
});

router.post("/test", function(req, res) {
    console.log("Hello...anyone!?");
    res.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

The GET works fine. I can pull http:/localhost:3000 right up in a browser.

When I fire a POST against http:/localhost:3000/test it results in a 400 Bad Gateway.

Comment: Have you tried putting post above get?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Yes...same result.

Comment: @TsarBomba Could you please share how you are firing the POST request?

Comment: @NehalJWani I'm using both Postman and Fiddler, and executing a POST against http:/localhost:3000/test

Comment: Strange. Your code runs for me without any problems.

Comment: instead of `app.use('/', index);` try with **app.use('*', index);**

Comment: @NehalJWani Weird...running it again returned a new message in Fiddler: "HTTP Request specified an invalid port number". I have to wonder if this is a system issue and something is goofy in Windows. Doesn't make sense though, since the get works fine on port 3000. It's not like something else is using the port. I even tried shutting down my firewall. No change.

Comment: @NehalJWani Changing the port the app runs on makes no difference, either.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, this had nothing to do with Node or the code posted. I rebooted my PC and the issue went away. I can't find anything that explains it.

Comment: Why the downvote? I clarified what my problem was, which I was completely unaware of when I originally posted. This very well could legitimately help someone. Lame.

Comment: Haters gonna hate. Keep doing your best and don't let them get you down.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone finds this helpful, I ran into the same issue and the culprit turned out to be missing headers. I knew I needed the `"Content-Type": "application/json"` header, which I already had in place, but I didn't know that I was missing two other headers.

**The solution for me** was also adding the `"Content-Length"` and `"Host"` headers in Postman.

I see some others have questioned the need for the `"Content-Length"` header, but in my case, the minimum three needed were `"Content-Type"`, `"Content-Length"`, and `"Host"` or it would always fail.